# How can I predict based on several time series of many different projects?

Tags: time-series, data-mining, prediction

I want to predict the time that a client takes to pay for a service that has already been received. We are talking about a construction company, so the payments are always overdue since the company spends money to build and is paid piecemeal afterwards.

I have data from many projects and for each project I have a few monthly time series of spent money, received money... (which in the same row is always less than the spent, or equal in an ideal world) and my response variable: number of days overdue.

To get an idea, this is the structure of the data where each row represents a month (of course with more rows and columns and many more experiments / projects):

[image: Data structure].

My first guess was to try some VARMA models since I'm experienced with ARIMA models, but there are too few rows and a few missings for the newest projects.

So, I need a bit of inspiration. What model should I try to predict a new Y variable based on the other available variables? Or at least to find some kind of relationship between Y's, since there are some types of projects.

Comment: vector arima or varma is only helpful if one experiment is influenced by the other.

Comment: Mm I was hoping to find some kind of relationship in that way. Anyway,  Varma is discarded and I don't reach to see any other clear way to make a forecast.

Comment: A lot of short time series ($N>T$) of unequal length reminds me of unbalanced panel data; maybe there is an answer in that strand of research? Also, I agree with @forecaster that VARMA does not make much sense if the projects are more of less independent.